# etcd not starting, getting error while probing status

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, etcd

I am trying to install Kubernetes, the hard way. Instead, of installing on GCP or using VirtualBox, I am installing on AWS. I'm using Red hat Linux image.

I am using 3 nodes for etcd in Stacked Topology. However, while starting the etcd service, it is giving the following error:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-08-01 17:03:37 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/coreos
  Process: 1816 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd --name ip-172-31-60-0 --cert-file=/etc/etcd/etcd-server.crt --key-file=/etc/etcd/etcd-server.key --peer-cert-file=/etc/etcd/etcd-server.crt --peer-key-file=/etc/etcd/etcd-server.key --trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.crt --peer-t>
 Main PID: 1816 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

I tried to look for a solution, can't get past it. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Exec status 203 alleges that [there is no such `/usr/local/bin/etcd`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2231#issuecomment-62148089); please do consider some searching if you want to do things "the hard way"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your case, but you could try to start the key-value store from scratch using the following command:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl del "" --from-key=true
sudo systemctl stop etcd
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/etcd/default.etcd
sudo systemctl start etcd
```

If that doesn't work, maybe the result of  `systemctl status etcd` may help troubleshooting...